# Barrel connector is too long for port

Tags: power-supply, plug, monitor

I had to buy an AC adapter for a monitor, but the one I purchased, while having the correct diameter for the plug, sticks out about a centimeter from the plug (picture below). This leaves part of the connector exposed. The adapter works fine otherwise, but I am curious if there are any risks of having this type of plug exposed to air. Would it be problematic to continue using it this way?

[image]

Comment: I would use a moldable plastic such as Polymorph.

Comment: No issues other than esthetics.

Comment: As noted by others, it's almost certain that the exposed metal is -ve output AND grounded. Very little chance of any issues. You could use an extension connector and bond (glue? :-) ) that plug in the socket and sleeve it - eg hotshrink. || There is SLIGHTLY more leverage from a sideways pull on the cord - pull prevention is always wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is center positive and barrel negative, then it's unlikely to cause any issues. The same connector size comes in multiple lengths so the connection should be fine. **As you can see, the other connectors like the d-sub vga or dvi connectors also have exposed metal. Those shells are normally grounded/negative.**

The issue can happen if it's center negative, barrel positive **AND** something conductive falls on it shorting it out to something negative. Possible but not super common. The opposite is true too, when some other connector is positive and shorts to your negative connector but outer shells being positive are less common.

[image]

You can tell which is which from the label on the monitor or from the power brick.

You can just wrap it in tape if you are really concerned.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like about 4mm, not a centimeter.

Not an issue unless you hang something on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two different kinds of barrel plugs. One type consists of a cylinder with a conductor on the outside diameter, and another conductor on the inside diameter. A second type of barrel plug, used for example in many Dell laptops, has a third conductor, which is recessed within the barrel, and located on the axis of the barrel.

If the barrel plug is of the first type, with only conductors on the inner and outer surfaces of the cylinder, then, as stated in another answer, there will probably be no problem with barrel plug being longer than the socket into which it is inserted.

However, if the barrel plug is of the second type, you are likely to experience difficulties, because the central electrode may not make contact with its appropriate partner.

[image: Barrel Plug with recessed 3rd conductor]Barrel plug showing recessed 3rd conductor. (from a Dell laptop power supply)